# MySQL Query Running Very Slow - But only some of them

Tags: mysql

I have a fresh Joomla 3.0 install that is running on MySQL and I'm using Workbench. I keep on running into very, very slow queries. However, it seems to be very few, specific queries. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM joom_users
```

runs very, very slow and often loses the connection. But UPDATE and INSERT work just fine into this table. Ive even imported a CSV file and it was blazing fast. I've already run

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM joom_users
```

There wasn't anything obviously wrong with the table. All the indexes are there and the table itself is pretty small (only about 300 rows). I've considered that the wildcard may be throwing it off, so I have replaced the wildcard with fields and I have tried querying from other tables with 2 fields (and, in some cases, with no rows) and that ALSO runs slow.

Also, requests to ALTER the tables are also running slow. Finally, I've also tried multiple machines with Workbench (one Win7, the other OSX) and they both run slowly, so Ive eliminated any local issues that could be causing this.

I'm perplexed by this. Help!

Comment: Is mysql running on a shared server?

Comment: @Jim Beam you dont understand the use of indexes or explain statement. SELECT * FROM joom_users can't and will not use indexes and should make a complete table scan and then return 300 records. Does the extra column give more  something like "Using temporary table" ?

Comment: Either the server is doing something else at those times (try reading the slowlog) or the table needs to get optimized after bigger changes. MyISAM has implicit locks on a lot of occasions. Try finding time patterns (maybe collision with backup?). I don't know if joomla would support InnoDB, but concurrency of requests is definitely better with InnoDB (as soon as you have enough ram).

Comment: @akatakritos yes, unfortunately it is a shared server. Its a Hatchling plan from HostGator which I know isnt ideal, but its what I've inherited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing implicitly wrong with the example query you've given. Theres no indexes it could use, but unless its a really wide table, I would expect it to be very fast.

In a shared server environment, you have no idea how many other databases are being hosted or how heavily they are being used. If you can migrate to a local database you'll be able to see if performance improves.

If you have 300 active users of your installation, there could be a lot of lock contention, especially on MyISAM which uses full table locks. For example, it looks like the Joomla users table has a `lastVisitDate`, which, if it is being updated on **every** page load by a logged in user, could definitely cause locking problems.